# C# LINQ Where Collection Contains

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am new to LINQ and I put this example together in order to obtain the count of items in the Artists collection which contain a Genre of Hip Hop or Pop. Any help with this example query would be appreciated!

```
private bool HasNonRockArtists()
{
   // Artists is a collection containing ArtistName and Genre.

   bool blnHasNonRockArtists = false;
   var genres = new List<string> { "HIP HOP", "POP" };

   var nonRockArtistsCount = (from a in Artists
                              where genres.Contains(a.Genre)
                              select a).Count();

   blnHasNonRockArtists = nonRockArtistsCount > 0 ? true : false;

   return blnHasNonRockArtists;
}
```

Comment: Change this `a.Genre.Contains(genres)` to this `genres.Contains(a.Genre)`

Comment: Also, you can use `Any(...)` instead of counting and a boolean.

Comment: `nonRockArtistsCount > 0 ? true : false;` can be shortened to `nonRockArtistsCount > 0;`

Comment: Many good solutions! I updated my question with the correct syntax in the where clause in my sample query which CodeNotFound had pointed out. Thanks all! \m/ \m/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the `Contains` method but not like you did.

You have send the element to the `Contains` method

```
var nonRockArtistsCount =  (from a in Artists 
                            where genres.Contains(a.Genre)
                            select a).Count();
```

Comment: Do not use this technique; it is inefficient. Heres a jar of a thousand coins; I want to know if it contains any dimes. **Do you have to count the dimes in order to know that?** Of course not. You'd stop after finding the first dime. As the other answers note, the correct answer is to use `Any` to represent the concept "are there any items which meet this predicate?"

Answer (score 1):

Full working console application example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleAppTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var artists = new List<Artist>();
            artists.Add(new Artist { Name = "Pearl Jam", Genre = "ROCK" });
            artists.Add(new Artist { Name = "Beyonce", Genre = "POP" });
            if (HasNonRockArtists(artists)) Console.WriteLine("The list contains non-rock artists.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string[] genres = new string[] { "HIP HOP", "POP" };
        private static bool HasNonRockArtists(List<Artist> artists)
        {
            return artists.Any(a => genres.Contains(a.Genre));
        }
        public class Artist
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Genre { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a one-liner and more modular!

```
private static bool HasArtistByGenres(IEnumerable<Artist> artists, IEnumerable<string> genres) => artists.Any(a => genres.Contains(a.genre));
```

If you don't like one liners:

```
private static bool HasArtistByGenres(IEnumerable<Arist> artists, IEnumerable<string> genres)
{
    return artists.Any(a => a.genres.Contains(a.genre);
}
```

If you prefer the more SQL-esque syntax:

```
private static bool HasArtistByGenres(IEnumerable<Arist> artists, IEnumerable<string> genres)
{
    return (from a in Artists where genres.Contains(a.genre) select a).Any();
}
```

Comment: You can make this more general still by using `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>`. There's nowhere that you depend on any ability of lists here.

Comment: Your first example has a syntax error; you don't use `return` in a `=>` style method.

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool HasNonRockArtists()
{
   var genres = new List<string> { "HIP HOP", "POP" };
   return Artists.Any(artist => genres.Contains(artist.Genre));
}
```

Comment: Hi Igor, since this seems to be your first answer in Stack Overflow, I suggest you read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to improve your future answers.